# Using "Disallow: /*?" in robots.txt file

Tags: robots.txt

I used

```
Disallow: /*?
```

in the robots.txt file to disallow all pages that might contain a "?" in the URL.

Is that syntax correct, or am I blocking other pages as well?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the bot.

Bots that follow the original robots.txt specification don’t give the `*` any special meaning. These bots would block any URL whose path starts with `/*`, directly followed by `?`, e.g., `http://example.com/*?foo`.

Some bots, including the Googlebot, give the `*` character a special meaning. It typically stands for any sequence of characters. These bots would block what you seem to intend: any URL with a `?`.

[Google’s robots.txt documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en) includes this very case:

> **To block access to all URLs that include question marks (`?`).** For example, the sample code blocks URLs that begin with your domain name, followed by any string, followed by a question mark, and ending with any string:
>
> ```
> User-agent: Googlebot
> Disallow: /*?
> ```