# Confusing wildcard in robots.txt: *+*, *%2B*, *%2b*

Tags: wildcard, robots.txt

What do these 3 lines mean in this robots.txt (obviously, I mean the `*+*`, `*%2B*`, and `*%2b*`)?

```
Disallow: /collections/*+*
Disallow: /collections/*%2B*
Disallow: /collections/*%2b*
```

Comment: [Question about the `*`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41140542/1591669)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The original ["standard"](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html) only defines

> Disallow
>   The value of this field specifies a partial URL that is not
>   to be visited. This can be a full path, or a partial path; any URL
>   that starts with this value will not be retrieved. For example,
>   `Disallow: /help` disallows both `/help.html` and `/help/index.html`,
>   whereas `Disallow: /help/` would disallow `/help/index.html` but allow
>   `/help.html`.

which means, that all paths **match literally** (no character has a special meaning as in pattern matching).

But it also states

> It is not an official standard backed by a standards body, or owned by any commercial organisation. It is not enforced by anybody...

---

### The more recent and modern [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt) explains

> Google, Bing, Yahoo, and Ask support a limited form of "wildcards" for path values. These are:
>
> - `*` designates 0 or more instances of any valid character.
> - `$` designates the end of the URL.

so

```
Disallow: /collections/*+*
Disallow: /collections/*%2B*
Disallow: /collections/*%2b*
```

will disallow all paths starting with `/collections/` followed by anything containing

- `+`
- `%2B`
- `%2b`

as these characters have no special meaning in a path pattern.